# node sessions not clearing in production

Tags: node.js, session

I am using client-sessions with node and express, and I am having trouble logging out users.

my logout function does a

```
req.session.user=null
```

that is:

```
userRouter.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.user = null
res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

(I also tried delete req.user, req.user.destroy(), and other variants).

in dev env, on localhost, it works great. 
in production environment, logout is called, but the next time the user refreshes the page on the browser, the user is still logged in.

same code in dev and production.

Anybody has any idea?
thanks....

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/12/using-secure-client-side-sessions-to-build-simple-and-scalable-node-js-applications-a-node-js-holiday-season-part-3/) on `client-sessions`, you can use this:

```
userRouter.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.reset(); 
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: thanks @robertklep, I had tried that but with no luck. And the funny thing is, the code works like a charme in localhost. also, on the server I can see the session, I can set it to null, but then when the user refreshes, it's like it is still there...

Comment: You should probably take a look at the request/response cycles in your browser's dev tools to see what happens when you reset the cookie. Also, does your production environment consist of only one server, or are there more than that?

Comment: one server only ( I mean, one is serving the client and one is for API)

Comment: And which server is handling the sessions? Have you tried serving both from a single (HTTP) server?

Comment: yep, same server. I have three functions in the same file, all getting http request and all handling sessions. two of them can read and write them. the logout one, magically, can read, but the writes do not affect the session. it might be because of race conditions (client making other requests with the same session at the same time?)

Comment: I was under the impression that you have two HTTP server processes (as you say, _"one is serving the client and one is for the API"_), but perhaps I misunderstood? Race conditions could be a cause, too, because every change in the session would mean that a new cookie has to be set, so if you have a "slow" request that may update the session and a "fast" request that resets/deletes it, the slow request may set the cookie again. That's a tough issue to deal with.

Comment: I think that's it then, even though, I kind of got the feeling that the cookie is the same and that the race conditions mess things up on the server?

Comment: Looking at the documentation of `client-sessions`, it has an option `activeDuration` which could cause the server sending a new cookie (or rather, the old cookie but with a different expiry time) for each request. Are you using that option? In any case, perhaps it would work better if you only use the `client-sessions` middleware for the specific requests that need it (and not as a "global" middleware that gets triggered for each request).

Comment: yeah I am using that, so the same session should be active, I am just not sure as to how updates to the request.session objects are managed. BTW the issues appears only on test server (which is much slower than my dev machine right now). also, thanks for your thoughts I really appreciate you taking the time. I put a fix that goes around the race conditions (made function shorter) but I am still not happy that race conditions can creep in as  I think if a session is destroyed it shouldn't magically pop back up.

Comment: When you're using a database-backed session store, the cookie only has to be set once, when a session was created, and the cookie only contains a session identifier. When session data is stored in the cookie itself, whenever a session has changed, the cookie has to be set again, which inherently introduces race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

so it the end the issue was that I did not have

```
headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
```

in the call from the client. I a bit puzzled by this, it seems as the server would set the session (through nginx) only if the client had this header, while in localhost it sets sessions correctly without this.

Comment: Are you caching proxy responses in NGINX, by any chance?

Comment: true answer is that I do not know... I have this directive proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

Comment: I don't think NGINX will cache proxy responses automatically, so unless you have it explicitly configured, it probably won't be caching.